# .NET 7 Rate Limiting - Rate limit by IP

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, rate-limiting

I want to set rate limit by user IP so in 1 minute he can send only 3 requests.

Also I want to set this to particular end-point. I have tried below code but it is not working.. so any idea on this..

I am using .NET Core 7

Program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("testRatelimit", context => RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(
        partitionKey: context.User.Identity?.Name ?? context.Request.Headers.Host.ToString(),
        factory: partition => new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
        {
            AutoReplenishment = true,
            PermitLimit = 3,
            QueueLimit = 0,
            Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        }));

    options.OnRejected = async (context, token) =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Too many requests. Please try later again... ", cancellationToken: token);
    };
});


var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRateLimiter();
```

In my controller I have added in thi way :

```
[EnableRateLimiting("testRatelimit")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("forgot-password")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(string email, bool? isAdmin)
        {
            return Ok(await userService.ForgotPassword(email, isAdmin ?? false));
        }
```

Comment: "UseRateLimiter must be called after UseRouting when rate limiting endpoint specific APIs are used. For example, if the [EnableRateLimiting] attribute is used, UseRateLimiter must be called after UseRouting." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/rate-limit?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to set rate limit by user IP so in 1 minute he can send only 3 requests.

Then you need to use IP as partitioning key, not the `context.User.Identity?.Name ?? context.Request.Headers.Host.ToString()`. Try something like:

```cs
options.AddPolicy("testRatelimit", context => RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(
    partitionKey: context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress,
    factory: // ...
    );
```

Comment: Just adding to this answer a warning; IP is not synonymous with user. For example, in NAT scenarios thousands of users can appear to have the same IP.

Comment: @Guru Stron can you please help me in this question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76317359/net-core-rate-limit-display-message-based-on-remaining-limit`