# .Net Core Rate limit display message based on remaining limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, rate-limiting

I have set rate limit for my one of the API, in that I have set like in 1 minute request can be sent for 3 times.. And then error will display in front end.

I am using Angular in front end, everything is working fine and below is code for that..

Now what I want is, I want to show message based on remaining limit. Like if user click one time in button then I want to show message some different and then user click again then need to show other message and once all attempt finished then display message.

So for this last part once all attempt finished then need to show message it is working fine, but for remaining limit I am not sure how to get that remaining limits.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("forgotPassword", context => RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(
        partitionKey: context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress,
        factory: partition => new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
        {
            AutoReplenishment = true,
            PermitLimit = 3,    
            Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        }));

    options.OnRejected = async (context, token) =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Too many requests. Please try later again... ", cancellationToken: token);
    };
});
```

My controller file :

```
 [EnableRateLimiting("forgotPassword")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(string email)
        {
            return Ok(await userService.ForgotPassword(email));
        }
```

Angular code :

```
this.apiService
      .fPassword(email)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        (res) => { // Here I want to show message based on remaining permit limit, if 1 limit is remaining then need to show some diff message and for 2 also some other message.
          if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            this.message("Success");
          } else {
            this.message('error!');
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          if(error.status == 429){
            this.message('Too many failed attempts');
          } else {
            this.message('error!');
          }
        }
      );
```

Comment: TBH I'm not sure that this is the right tool for the task. There are quite a lot potential problems here -  first one would be multiple deployments of the app (without some kind of sticky load balancing). I would suggest to look into using some kind of outside storage to monitor/store the data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that doing this directly through the rate limit middleware will not be possible. The alternative I see is for you to count how many requests have been made to the endpoint where you set the rate limit and subtract according to the limit you set in your rate limit window.
In your example, the permit limit is three, which means you can count how many requests have occurred at the endpoint where you configured the rate limit. With this, you can control and display a message on the frontend.